# I keep getting an "error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant expression" from previously used working code

Tags: c++, eos

I've been scratching my head for days now. Gone step by step removing and adding lines and recompiling at each stage until it breaks.

```
  ACTION act1(name nm, uint64_t amount);
  ACTION act2(name nm, uint64_t signing_value);
  ACTION receiverand(name nm, checksum256& random_value);
  ACTION act4(name nm, uint64_t stake);
  ACTION act5(uint64_t num);
  ACTION act6(name nm);

  using act1_action = action_wrapper<"act1"_n, &project::act1>;
  using act2_action = action_wrapper<"act2"_n, &project::act2>;
  using receiverand_action = action_wrapper<"receiverand"_n, &project::receiverand>;
  using act4_action = action_wrapper<"act4"_n, &project::act4>;
  using act5_action = action_wrapper<"act5"_n, &project::act5>;
  using act6_action = action_wrapper<"act6"_n, &project::act6>;
```

The problem arises when I add act6. I had up to act4 and everything was working. So I added 5 and 6 then the error was thrown so I went back added 5 and things were still okay.
Here is the error I keep getting

```
 error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant expression
        constexpr auto x = 
        eosio::name{std::string_view{eosio::detail::to_const_char_arr<Str...>::value, 
        sizeof...(Str)}};

  note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator""_n<char, 'a', 
        'c', 't', '6'>' requested here
        using act6_action = action_wrapper<"act6"_n, &project::act6>;

 note: non-constexpr function 'check' cannot be used in a constant expression
       eosio::check( false, "character is not in allowed character set for names" );
```

Comment: What happens when using "act6" for ::act5, and never referencing ::act6? And vice versa? (That is, is the issue related to the first or second parameter..?)

Comment: you mean comment out " using act6_action = action_wrapper<"act6"_n, &project::act6>;" and change the act5 line to reference act6?
like so:
  'using act5_action = action_wrapper<"act5"_n, &project::act6>;
  //using act6_action = action_wrapper<"act6"_n, &project::act6>;'

Comment: Sure, that’d one variation or check.

Comment: just threw this error: action not a valid eosio name
      ACTION act6(name nm);
ill try changing the whole line to act6 instead of just the last part

Comment: i tried every variation they all threw one of the two errors

Comment: Is `project::act6` same as `ACTION act6` defined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears that a name cannot contain the character `'6'`, but only `'1'` thru `'5'`.

> ```
> Action names [...] May contain: a-z, 1-5, or .
> ```

https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-are-naming-rules-for-actions-tables-and-contracts

Comment: Thank you! Should of realized that. Wallet addresses can only have 1-5